# Logistic growth curve using scipy is not quite right

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations

I'm trying to fit a simple logistic growth model to dummy data using Python's `Scipy` package. The code is shown below, along with the output that I get. The correct output is shown below it. I'm not quite sure what's going wrong here.

```
import scipy.optimize as optim
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N0 = 0.37
parsic = [.25, 12.9]

df_yeast = pd.DataFrame({'cd': [9.6, 18.3, 29., 47.2, 71.1, 119.1, 174.6, 257.3, 350.7, 441., 513.3, 559.7, 594.8, 629.4, 640.8, 651.1, 655.9, 659.6], 'td': np.arange(18)})

def logistic_de(t, N, r, K):
    return r*N*(1 - N/K)

def logistic_solution(t, r, K):
    return odeint(logistic_de, N0, t, (r, K), tfirst=True).ravel()

params, _ = optim.curve_fit(logistic_solution, df_yeast['td'], df_yeast['cd'], p0=parsic)

N1 = odeint(logistic_de, N0, np.linspace(0, 20, 10000), (params[0], params[1]), tfirst=True)

plt.plot(np.linspace(0, 20, 10000), N1)
plt.scatter(df_yeast['td'], df_yeast['cd'])
plt.ylabel('num yeast')
plt.xlabel('time')
```

My output:
[image]

Correct output:
[image]

Comment: Add the initial value `N0` to the parameters that get optimized. Compare the first data point `9.6` to your initial value of `0.37`.

Comment: That works quite well and results in the parameters `r=0.5476140280399281, K=662.6552616132678, N0=9.10156146739931`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To repeat the answers you got at your cross-post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69292456/logistic-growth-curve-using-scipy-is-not-quite-right

The logistic curve is rather rigid in its symmetry. Forcing the initial value to be some prescribed constant effectively removes a degree of freedom in the family of curves that are available to the fitting process.

Thus include `N0` in the set of parameters, do not forget to unpack it for the computation for the plot, and you will get a fitted solution that looks like your second graph with parameters `r=0.5476140280399281, K=662.6552616132678, N0=9.10156146739931`

Changes in code were

```python
parsic = [.25, 12.9, N0]
...
def logistic_solution(t, r, K, N0):
    return odeint(logistic_de, N0, t, (r, K), tfirst=True, atol=1e-6, rtol=1e-9).ravel()
...
t = np.linspace(0, 20, 1000)
N1 = logistic_solution(t, *params)
plt.plot(t, N1)
```